# How to forward and backward the WebRTC stream video in android?

Tags: android, webrtc, streaming, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I am developing an application having amazon-kinesis-video-webrtc SDK for android.
I am able to play the live stream video in the app.
Also I am able to play and pause the video using `remoteView.disableFpsReduction();` and `remoteView.pauseVideo();`. But now I want to forward and backward the video up to 10 seconds.

I have searched on the internet but could not find the solution for the same. Can anyone please help me **Is there any direct methods available for this or do I need to use the other approach if there is any?**

Please help!